# How do I convert parts of the string to uppercase?

Tags: php

I have a string that I want to convert to uppercase apart from the word 'and' which is always surrounded by underscores.

So me_and_you becomes ME_and_YOU
The string doesn't always contain 'and' so it could be me_you becomes ME_YOU

Obviously strtoupper() makes the whole thing uppercase. Will I have to use something like preg_split() or explode()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably write a regex to do that, but an easy alternative solution would be:

```
echo str_replace('_AND_', '_and_', strtoupper($your_string));
```

Comment: Was hoping there would be something simple! Silly me, clever you! :)